# Data structure for finding maximum of subarrays in better than O(log n) expected time

Tags: arrays, data-structures, language-agnostic, time-complexity

Given an array of values, how can you build a data structure that lets you find the maximum of any contiguous subarray quickly? Ideally the overhead of building this structure should be small and the structure should allow efficient appends and mutation of single elements.

An example array would be `[6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 1, 0, 3]`. A request may be to find the maximum of the slice from index 2 to 7 (subarray `[3, 7, 5, 1, 0]`), which would result in `7`.

Comment: Unfortunately my Google searches for this were crowded out by many much more basic questions sharing similar terms. If anyone knows how to clarify or improve the Google-ability of this Q&A (or has found any related material I failed to), please share.

Comment: For the record I just googled "data structure to repeatedly query maximum of subarray" and this question was the second result. So I would say the Google-ability is pretty good :)

Comment: Related: [Maximum minimum of any subarray in constant time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408632/maximum-minimum-of-any-subarray-in-constant-time/73418122#73418122)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `n` be the length of the array and `k` be the length of the slice.

#### The naïve, `O(log k)`, method

An obvious solution is to build a tree that repeatedly gives a pairwise summary of the maximums

```
1 8 4 5 4 0 1 5 6 9 1 7 0 4 0 9 0 7 0 4 5 7 4 3 4 6 3 8 2 4 · ·
 8   5   4   5   9   7   4   9   7   4   7   4   6   8   4   ·
   8       5       9       9       7       7       8       4
       8               9               7               8
               9                               8
                               9
```

These summaries take at most `O(n)` space, and the lower levels can be stored efficiently by using short indices. The bottom level, for example, can be a bit array. Appends and single mutations take `O(log n)` time. There are many other areas for optimization if need be.

The chosen slice can be split into two slices, split on a boundary between two triangles. In this example, for a given slice we'd split as so:

```
                   |---------------------------------|
                6 9 1 7 0 4 0 9|0 7 0 4 5 7 4 3 4 6 3 8 2 4 · ·
                 9   7   4   9 | 7   4   7   4   6   8   4   ·
                   9       9   |   7       7       8       4
                       9       |       7               8
                               |               8
```

In each triangle we are interested in a [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#forest) of these trees that minimally determines the elements we actually care about:

```
                   |---------------------------------|
                    1 7 0 4 0 9|0 7 0 4 5 7 4 3 4 6 3
                     7   4   9 | 7   4   7   4   6
                           9   |   7       7
                               |       7
```

Note that in this case there are two trees on the left and three on the right. The total number of trees will be at most `O(log k)`, since there are at most two of any given height. We can find the splitting point with a little bit-math

```
round_to = (start ^ end).bit_length() - 1
split_point = (end >> height) << height
```

Note that Python's `bit_length` can be done quickly with the `lzcnt` instruction on x86 architectures. The relevant trees are on each side of the split. The sizes of the relevant subtrees are encoded in the bits of the residuals of these numbers:

```
lhs_residuals = split_point - start
rhs_residuals = end - split_point

bin(lhs_residuals)
# eg.     10010110
# sizes = 10000000
#            10000
#              100
#               10
```

It's hard to traverse the most significant bits of an integer, but if you do a bit swap (a byteswap instruction plus a few shift-and-masks) you can then traverse the lowest significant bits by iterating this:

```
new_value = value & (value - 1)
lowest_set_bit = value ^ new_value
value = new_value
```

A traversal down the left and right halves takes `O(log k)` expected time because there are at most `2log₂ k` trees - one per bit for each side.

#### A tangent: handling residuals in `O(1)` time and `O(n log n)` space

`O(log k)` is better than `O(log n)`, but it's still not groundbreaking. One helpful effect of the previous attempt is that the trees to each side are "attached" to one side; there are only `n` ranges in their slice, not `n²` for an arbitrary slice. You can utilize this by adding to each level cumulative maxima, as so:

```
1 8 4 5 4 0 1 5 6 9 1 7 0 4 0 9 0 7 0 4 5 7 4 3 4 6 3 8 2 4 · ·

- 8|- 5|- 4|- 5|- 9|- 7|- 4|- 9|- 7|- 4|- 7|- 4|- 6|- 8|- 4|- ·  left to right
8 -|5 -|4 -|5 -|9 -|7 -|4 -|9 -|7 -|4 -|7 -|4 -|6 -|8 -|4 -|· -  right to left

- - 8 8|- - 4 5|- - 9 9|- - 4 9|- - 7 7|- - 7 7|- - 6 8|- - · ·  left to right
8 8 - -|5 5 - -|9 9 - -|9 9 - -|7 7 - -|7 7 - -|8 8 - -|4 4 - -  right to left

- - - - 8 8 8 8|- - - - 9 9 9 9|- - - - 7 7 7 7|- - - - 8 8 · ·  left to right
8 8 5 5 - - - -|9 9 9 9 - - - -|7 7 7 7 - - - -|8 8 8 8 - - - -  right to left

- - - - - - - - 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9|- - - - - - - - 7 7 7 8 8 8 · ·  left to right
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 - - - - - - - -|8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 - - - - - - - -  right to left

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 · ·  left to right
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  right to left
```

The marker `-` is used to ignore those parts necessarily the same as the level below them, which do not need to be copied. In this case, the relevant slices are

```
                   |---------------------------------|
                    1 7 0 4 0 9 0 7 0 4 5 7 4 3 4 6 3
                    ↓                               ↓
                9 9 9 9 - - - -|- - - - - - - - 7 7 7 8 8 8 · ·
                 right to left | left to right
```

and the wanted maxima are as indicated. The true maxima is then the maximum of those two values.

This obviously takes `O(n log n)` memory, since there are `log n` levels and each needs a complete row of values (though they can be indexes to save space). Updates, however, take `O(n)` time as they may propagate - adding a 10 to this would invalidate the whole bottom right-to-left row, for example. Mutations are obviously equally inefficient.

#### `O(1)` time by answering a different question

Depending on the context you need this for, you may find it is possible to truncate the search depth. This works if you are allowed some leeway in your slice relative to the size of the slice. Since the slices shrink geometrically, although a slice from `0:4294967295` takes a massive 22 iterations, truncating to a fixed quantity of 11 iterations gives the maximum of the slice `0:4292870144`, a 0.05% difference. This may be acceptable.

#### `O(1)` *expected* time by exploiting probability

Rounding may be acceptable, but even if it is you're still doing an `O(log n)` algorithm - just with a smaller, fixed `n`. It is possible to do a lot better on randomly distributed data.

Consider one side of a forest. As you traverse down it, the fraction of numbers you've seen exceeds the fraction you haven't seen geometrically. Thus the probability that you've already seen the maximum increases in par. It makes sense that you can use this to your advantage.

Consider this half again:

```
---------------------|
0 7 0 4 5 7 4 3 4 6 3 8 2 4 · ·
 7   4   7   4   6*  8   4   ·
   7       7       8*      4
       7*              8
               8
```

After checking the `7*`, don't immediately traverse to the `6*`. Instead, check the smallest parent of *all* of the rest, which is the `8*`. Only traverse down if this parent is larger than the maximum so far. If it is not, you can stop iterating. Only if it is larger do you need to continue traversing down. It just so happens that the largest values is one past the end here, so we traverse all the way down, but you can imagine this is unusual.

At least half of the time you only need to evaluate the first triangle, at least half of the rest you only need to look down once more, etc. This is a geometric sequence that shows the average traversal cost is *two* traversals; less if you include the fact that the remaining triangles can be less than half the size some of the time.

#### And in the worst case?

The worst case occurs with nonrandom trees. The most pathological is sorted data:

```
---------------------|
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
 1   3   5   7   9   b   d   f
   3       7       b       f
       7               f
               f
```

Since the maximum is always in the fragment of the range you haven't seen, regardless of which slice you choose. Thus the traversal is always `O(log n)`. Unfortunately sorted data is frequent in practice, and this algorithm is hurt here (this property is shared with several other algorithms, like quicksort). It is possible to mitigate the harm, though.

#### Not dying on sorted data

If each node says whether it's sorted, or sorted in reverse, then upon reaching that node you don't need to do any more traversal - you can just take the first or last element in the subarray.

```
---------------------|
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
 →   →   →   →   →   →   →   →
   →       →       →       →
       →               →
               →
```

You might find you instead have mostly-sorted data with some small randomization, though, which breaks the scheme:

```
---------------------|
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a 9 a b d 0 e f
 →   →   →   →   ←   →   ←   →
   →       →       b       f
       →               f
               f
```

so instead each node can have the maximum number of levels down you can go whilst remaining sorted, and in which direction. You then skip down that many iterations. An example:

```
---------------------|
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a 9 a b d 0 e f

→1  →1  →1  →1  ←1  →1  ←1  →1
 0   3   5   7   a   b   d   f
  →2      →2      →1      →1
   3       7       b       f
      →3              →2
       7               f
              →3
               f
```

`→n` means if you skip down `n` levels the nodes will all be sorted left to right. The top node is `→3` because three levels down is ordered: `0 3 5 7 a b d f`. The direction is easy to encode in a single bit. Thus mostly-sortedness is handled gracefully.

This is easy to keep updated, because each node can calculate its value from its direct children. If they agree and are sorted in the same direction they agree, the the minimum distance and add one. Otherwise reset to a distance of `1` and point in the direction the children are sorted. The hardest part is the logic in traversal, which looks a bit finicky.

It is still possible to produce examples that require traversal all the way to the bottom, but they should not occur frequently in non-adversarial data.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered by coincidence the term for this problem:

#### Range minimum query

Unsurprisingly, this is a well-studied problem, albeit one it seems hard to search for. [Wikipedia gives some solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) which are noticeably different to mine.

The `O(1)` time, `O(n log n)` space solution in particular is much more effective than my similar aside, since it allows appends in `O(log n)` time, which may suffice, rather than the terrible `O(n)` mine caused.

The other approaches are asymptotically decent, and the final result is particularly good. The `O(log n)` time, `O(n)` space solution is technically weaker than my final result, but `log n` is never large and it has better constant factors on search due to its linear scan of memory. Appending elements in both cases is amortized `O(1)`, with the Wikipedia variant doing better with sufficient care. I would expect setting the block size to something fixed and applying the algorithm straightforwardly would be a practical win. In my case, even excessive block sizes of, say, 128 would be plenty fast for searches, and minimise both overhead on append and the constant factor of the space overhead.

The final constant-time approach seems like an academic result of little practical use.