# How to efficiently calculate the sum of several slices of a vector?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, dynamic-programming

If I have, lets say a vector with millions of elements and I keep being asked what is the sum of all elements of a slice of this vector, what data structure would be suitable for this task?

I could just iterate over the slice, but it seems like I'm wasting some previous calculations if I keep doing that all the time. If I calculate the sum for `v[500_000..750_000]` and them calculate the sum of `v[400_000..600_000]` there is an overlap between those, and it seems I could use some dynamic programing to reuse calculations.

Comment: Do the elements of the vector change over time? Is any slice as likely to be of interest as any other?

Comment: No, the the elements do not change. The slices are random, so they are equally likely.

Comment: Perhaps a binary tree where a root stores the sum of the entire array and each branch stores the sum of the corresponding half.

Comment: Just [compute the prefix sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). If the sum up to index `i-1` is `x` and the sum up to index `j` is `y`, then the slice from `i` to `j` inclusive has sum `y - x`

Comment: If the values don't change, I guess the prefix sum is better, but if they change maybe the binary tree would be better. I am also wondering if it is possible to generalize for other stats like maximum and minimum of the slice.

Comment: For max + min, the magic google words are "range minimum query".  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408632/maximum-minimum-of-any-subarray-in-constant-time/73418122#73418122

Comment: In general, you should be able to answer such queries of any associative operation (`max`, `min`, arithmetic operations, etc.) in logarithmic time with a segment tree-like structure, as suggested by @n.m.. Of course, better algorithms for specific cases, like the range minimum query algorithm, may exist.

Comment: If you have to process offline query about fixed vector's range sum, search about `prefix sum`. Each query will be O(1) after O(n) pre-processing the prefix sum.

Comment: @EvilTak, that was the term I was looking for but I did not know the name. A segment tree. I had never heard of it before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're many ways to approach your problem, which arises very frequently in programming. The data structures below are roughly sort in difficulty in ascending order. (Earlier means easier)

1. **Prefix sum**: Compute a[0..0] a[0..1], a[0..2], a[0..3], .., a[0..N-1], then you can get a[l...r] by a[0..r] - a[0..l - 1].
   Complexity: O(N) preprocessing, O(1) query
2. **Sparse table**: Make a 2d array with dimensions st[log N][N], where st[i][j] stores the sum a[j...j+2^i-1]
   Complexity: O(NlogN) preprocessing, O(log N) query
3. **Segment tree**: Essentially a binary tree where each vertex stores the sum of some segment of the array. E.g., the root stores a[0..N-1], the children of the root store a[0..(N-1)/2] and a[0..(N+1)/2] respectively, and the rest continues recursively.
   However, the power of segment tree really lies in the ability to modify element. Using it for range sum query on immutable array is an overkill which introduces unnecessary memory usage.
   Complexity: O(NlogN) preprocessing O(log N) query

In general **prefix sum** should be the way to go for unless you need other functionality later on, because it's the most intuitive and efficient in terms of both memory and runtime. All of these also incorporate the concept of dynamic programming inside.