# Seeking a Linear Time Complexity Algorithm for Maximum Strength Query with Variable Range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, sliding-window

I'm tackling a challenging problem and seeking assistance to find a solution with linear time complexity (`Theta(n)`). The objective is to compute the maximum strength a creature can harness from a variable number of preceding creatures in a line.

**Problem Overview:**
We have two lists, `x` and `k`, of equal length, representing attributes of creatures in a line. List `x` contains the strengths of these creatures, while list `k` indicates the count of creatures in front of the `i-th` creature (including itself) it can call upon for assistance.

**Detailed Example:**
Consider `x = [5, 10, 7, 2, 20]` and `k = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2]`. For each creature, we need to find the maximum strength available to it based on `k`. For instance, for the fourth creature (index 3):

- It can consider up to 3 creatures (itself and two before it), as `k[3] = 3`.
- The strengths to consider are `[10, 7, 2]`.
- Thus, the maximum strength it can use is `max([10, 7, 2]) = 10`.

We aim to create a list where each element is the maximum strength accessible to each creature, as described.

**Current Algorithm and Its Limitation:**

```py
def calculate_xj(x, k):
    x_j = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        start_index = max(0, i - k[i])
        end_index = i + 1
        x_j.append(max(x[start_index:end_index]))
    return x_j
```

This algorithm doesn't achieve linear time complexity. The primary issue is the use of the `max` function within the loop, which iterates over each element in the sliced list. This results in a nested iteration, leading to O(n^2) complexity, as for each creature, we potentially iterate over a list subset, varying based on `k`.

**Seeking Suggestions:**
I'm looking for algorithms or data structures that can achieve this calculation in linear time. Any guidance on optimizing my current approach or suggesting a new algorithm, particularly those utilizing sliding windows or other techniques suitable for variable-range calculations, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to do this in linear time?

Comment: I agree with @trincot. `O(n log(n))` is easy, and I wouldn't expect to be able to do better than that.

Comment: BTW, your `start_index` is wrong. For your example input, the output for index 2 should return 7 (only one value in `x` should be considered, which is 7). Yet, your code outputs 10 for index 2.

Comment: You can do this in linear time.  The google words are "range minimum query'.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408632/maximum-minimum-of-any-subarray-in-constant-time/73418122#73418122