# Recreate a O(n*k) algorithm to Θ(n)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

You have 2 int[] arrays with same length on input - x, k.

Each element in array x tells you the power level of the given index.

Each element in array k tells you the number of power levels to choose from array x(including itself).

These are the conditions for the arrays: `(∀i ∈ {1, . . . , n − 1})(1 ≤ ki+1 ≤ ki + 1)`
Try to return index (j) of the most powerful index for each group in x defined by ki. x`j =max{xs |i−ki <s≤i}` with time-complexity Θ(n) where n is the length of the arrays.

I've made a naive solution that is O(n*k) where k represents the use of max() to find the max number in each subarray:

```
"""
    (∀i ∈ {1, . . . , n − 1})(1 ≤ ki+1 ≤ ki + 1)
    max{xs |i−ki < s ≤ i}
"""
x = [1000, 4, 3, 2, 500, 10, 1]
k = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]

for i in range(len(x)):
    group = max(x[i - k[i] + 1 : i - k[i] + 1 + k[i]])
    print(x.index(group), end=" ")
```

Correct output for the input in the code block is:
`0 0 1 1 4 4 6`

```
x1 -> k1 == 1: we are only choosing from x1(1000) -> in that case we return the first index
x2 -> k2 == 2: we are choosing from x1, x2(1000, 4) -> first index is larger so we return it
x3 -> k3 == 2: x2, x3 -> second index is the largest
x4 -> k4 == 3: x2, x3, x4 -> second index is the largest
x5 -> k5 == 2: x4, x5
x6 -> k6 == 3: x4, x5, x6
x7 -> k7 == 1: x7
```

Maybe it could be done with queue??

Comment: Can k ever increase by more than 1? Could k7 be 5?

Comment: @MatBailie this is the condition for k (1 ≤ ki+1 ≤ ki + 1). k7(ki+1) can't be 5 because it would then be larger than k6(ki + 1) - hence the condition would be false.

Comment: I don't understand that notation. Does it mean that because k6 is 3, k7 must be between 1 and 4?  (Having `ki+1` mean something different to `ki + 1` makes me think you have missing brackets; `1 <= k[i+1] <= k[i] + 1` perhaps?)

Comment: @MatBailie it means that k7 must be smaller or equal to k6 + 1 (between 1-4 as you say). 1 <= k[i+1] <= k[i] + 1 is correct.

Comment: Are the x values unique?  If not, what should happen when the largest found value appears multiple times in the search range?

Comment: @MatBailie in that case all of them are correct answers, but you may return only one index

Comment: Is each value of `k` truly random (for its allowable range), or is there a propensity for it to grow/diminish/etc?  *(If it's truly random, it will usually stay very small.)*  I also presume that this is for very large values of `n`?

Comment: @MatBailie the only mention for the values of k is the condition which we already discussed, it's quite a weird task

Comment: Then approximate 1/3 of the time `k=1`, and 1/3 of the time `k=2`.  With that being the case, `max()` and `index()` are not major limiting factors.  Any optimisation I can think of slows it down in more cases than it helps *(even in a million long list, k will rarely exceed 10)*  For example; https://trinket.io/python3/d350484b70

Comment: @MatBailie the thing is that it needs to be Θ(n) tho :/ It's more of a theoretical question than a practical one.

Comment: The number xi indicates the degree of protection that the being in the i-th position is able to provide.
The number ki then indicates the number of beings standing in front of the being in the ith position (including itself) to which it can turn for help in case of emergency, and in addition holds ( 1 ≤ ki+1 ≤ ki + 1). For each i-th creature (i = 1,2,...,n) in turn, list the index of the creature to which the i-th creature can turn in case of emergency and which of them provides the greatest degree of protect-for each element in the field x write the number j such that xj =max{xs |i−ki <s≤i}.

Comment: Because of the behaviour of `k`, it very nearly is O(n).  For example, a one million long list takes about 1200x as long a one thousand long list.  https://trinket.io/python3/dd5ecc8623

Comment: @MatBailie so how would one prove, that it cannot be solved more efficiently?

Comment: what about range minimum query?

Comment: Aargh.  That's 3 RMQ questions this week!  You guys must be taking the same course.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408632/maximum-minimum-of-any-subarray-in-constant-time/73418122#73418122

Answer (score 0):

It's challenging to assert that accessing the maximum of a sublist in O(1) is feasible when the input for the array k is typically treated as variable. Your situation is the range max query problem, where enhancing query time might involve accessing the maximum in a sublist in O(log n) which gives you an overall of O(k*log(n)) worst case scenario. Refer to segment tree ressources to understand the range query problems.

For implementing a solution using a segment tree for your problem, you can refer to this link: Range [Range Max Query Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-2-range-maximum-query-node-update/)

Comment: Thx for the answer. It should be possible in Θ(n) or O(n) tho. At least the creator of the problem said so.