# Find sum of items in given range

Tags: java, algorithm

Given 4 arrays:

1. keys array
2. values array
3. left array
4. right array

For example:

keys = [1,2,1,1,3]
values = [5,3,4,5,2]
left = [0,0]
right = [2,4]

size of arrays keys and values are same. similarly size of left and right arrays are same and it represents the queries on our keys and values

left and right indicates the index positions range from left to right to pick items from keys and values

Task is to pick the keys and the corresponding maximum value in the provided range from left to right.

Add all the corresponding maximum values collected in above step to result.

This range of keys and values should be ignored while evaluating next combination of left to right range

**Explanation:**

a) left = 0, right = 2

we have keys = [1,2,1] values = [5,3,4]

for key = 1 max value is 5, for key = 2 max value is 3, so sum is 5 + 3 = 8

b) left = 0, right = 4

we have already processed 0 to 2 in above step, so we need to pick only 3 to 4

so we have keys = [1,3], values = [5,2]

for key 1 max value os 5, for key=3 max value is 2, so sum is 5+2 = 7

So our result should hold values [8,7]

Here is my code using brute force or naive approach:

```
public List<Integer> solve(int[] keys, int[] values, int[] left, int[] right) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<left.length; i++) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int j=left[i]; j<=right[i]; j++) {
            int last = map.getOrDefault(keys[j], 0);
            map.put(keys[j], Math.max(last, values[j]);
            values[j] = 0; // to skip this in next iteration
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(int e : map.values()) sum += e;
        result.add(e);
    }
    return result;  
}
```

My code runs in O(n^2), how to reduce time complexity for this program.

Comment: Hello. When you say *"My code runs in O(n^2)"*, what is n?

Comment: This similar question might help: [Data structure for finding maximum of subarrays in better than O(log n) expected time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141793/data-structure-for-finding-maximum-of-subarrays-in-better-than-olog-n-expected)

Comment: I don't follow; please explain exactly what `left` and `right` are.

Comment: 2nd RMQ question is as many days.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408632/maximum-minimum-of-any-subarray-in-constant-time/73418122#73418122

Comment: If your code works, it might be better suited for [Code Review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77909825/find-sum-of-items-in-given-range)

Comment: Why not compute a _map_ of keys to max values? Then you just need to compute a _set_ of keys within the given range, and sum the corresponding maximums? No nested loops there.

Comment: @Bohemian, left is the starting index of keys to consider and right is the ending index for the keys array. They indicate a range of indices [left to right]

Comment: It seems that a [segment tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html) would be useful for this problem. The sum of values between specified keys can be thought of as a variant of a range query, whereas "...this range of keys and values should be ignored while evaluating next combination of left to right range" would be equivalent to an update query, where you'd want to simulate replacing each key with its second-to-largest value in a fast way.

Answer (score 0):

First step: get a map of all of the max values for each key. Once this information is stored, we'll never have to calculate it again, much less for each range we are evaluating.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> maxValues = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    int curMax = map.getOrDefault(keys[i], 0);
    if (values[i] > curMax)
        map.put(keys[i], values[i])
}
```

Now you need never calculate the maximum value for a given key again.

If we have a range denoted by `left` and `right`, we need to calculate a set of keys.

```
Set<Integer> keysSetInRange = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
    keysSetInRange.add(keys[i]);
}
```

Now to get a sum, you simply have to iterate over this set, find the max value associated with each key, and add them up.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int k : keysSetInRange) {
    sum += maxValues[k];
}
```

As each of these individual map and set operations occurs in roughly constant time, we can say complexity is O(n).

Comment: Wouldn't complexity be O(nk), where n is length of the keys and values arrays, and k is length of the left and right arrays?

Comment: For example if input is `keys = [1,1,1,1,1] values = [5,6,7,8,9] left = [0,0] right = [2,4]` . As per this logic maxValues = {1, 9}. Now for range [0,2] -> max should be 6 for this example, also for [0.4] max will be 9, so result holds [6,9]. But this answer gives me [9,9]. Let me know if I am missing anything